# Whenever I'm trying to create new project in Unreal Engine5 I'm getting this problem

Tags: visual-c++, unreal-engine5, unreal-development-kit

An error occurred while trying to generate project files.

Running D:/UE_5.1/Engine/Build/BatchFiles/Build.bat  -projectfiles -project="D:/unreal projects/MyProject2/MyProject2.uproject" -game -rocket -progress
Running UnrealBuildTool: dotnet "....\Engine\Binaries\DotNET\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.dll" -projectfiles -project="D:/unreal projects/MyProject2/MyProject2.uproject" -game -rocket -progress
'dotnet' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I want to know what's the problem and how to resolve it.

Comment: Do you have dotnet installed? https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download

Answer (score 1):

Try installing or updating your Dotnet framework.

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download is where you can get the latest. Then open your command prompt or terminal, and try `dotnet --version`
Then try to build again.

```
Running D:/UE_5.1/Engine/Build/BatchFiles/Build.bat -projectfiles -project="D:/unreal projects/MyProject2/MyProject2.uproject" -game -rocket -progress Running UnrealBuildTool: dotnet "....\Engine\Binaries\DotNET\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.dll" -projectfiles -project="D:/unreal projects/MyProject2/MyProject2.uproject" -game -rocket -progress 'dotnet' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```